# Handling missing data using aregImpute() in R

Tags: r, prediction, missing-data

I am new to R and I am using `rms` package for handling imputations. I noticed that the `aregImpute` function in `rms` only returns column values which has NA values.

```
impute <- aregImpute(Y~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6,data= train_data, n.impute=5, nk=0)
impute$imputed$Y
```

When I tried to find the target value in the imputed data set using `impute$imputed$Y`, it returned `NULL`. According to my understanding, because target variable had no `NA` values I got `NULL`. My query is that how can I combine imputed dataset with the original dataset so that I will have the complete data set with no `NA` values. I actually want to try out various algorithm like `Decision Tree`, `Random Forest` with the imputed data. Does anyone have any suggestion. It would be a great help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  To help make a reproducible example, you can use   `reproduce(<your data>)` . Instructions are here: http://bit.ly/SORepro   -  [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://bit.ly/SORepro)

Comment: You can use `completeData <- impute.transcan(impute, imputation=1, data=train_data, list.out=TRUE,pr=FALSE, check=FALSE)` to impute the first iteration of imputation values. Then use `cbind.data.frame(completeData)` to create a data frame. (or to impute manually for variable `x1`: `train_data$X1[impute$na$X1] <- impute$imputed$X1[,1]`). This only uses the first imputation (out of 5) so does not use the variation in imputation. [Might be worth having a look at the `mice` package]